# Second Set of Eyes: One custom taxonomy shows in Appearance > Menus, one does not

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus

I presume this is a scenario where I've overlooked something in syntax, or a basic setting. But I've looked it over so many times I need fresh eyes.

I have the following code which adds a Product CPT, then a Product Group taxonomy (tag), and a Product Category taxonomy.

The Products and Product Group show in Appearance > Menus, Product Category does not.
Help?

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function products_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Products', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Product', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Products', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Product:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Products', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'New Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search products', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No products found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No products found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Product', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Product information pages.', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'product_category' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-chart-line',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'products', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'products_post_type', 0 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'product_category' ) ) {

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function product_category() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Product Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Product Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Product Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Category Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Categories list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Categories list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'product_category', array( 'products' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'product_category', 0 );

}

if ( ! function_exists( 'product_group' ) ) {

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function product_group() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Product Groups', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Product Group', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Product Groups', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Product Group', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Product Groups with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Product Groups', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Product Groups', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Product Groups', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Product Groups', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Product Groups list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Product Groups list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'product-group',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'product_group', array( 'products' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'product_group', 0 );

}
```

Comment: Have you visited the Permalink Settings page to flush rewrite rules? You could also try unregister_post_type() right before re-registering the CPT, then visiting that permalinks page, to flush what's already there.

Comment: @WebElaine just gave that a go, to no avail. I have toggled the true/false of show_in_nav_menus and had the CPT and Product Group behave properly...

Comment: i just copied and pasted your code.  It works fine in both the CPT structure and when i go to the appearance/ menu section.  Have you checked under screen options on the menus section to see if you have it hidden?

Comment: @rudtek winner winner chicken dinner. THANK YOU. (yes, I warned it was likely something simple and silly ... happens to the best of us)

Comment: Good to hear!  Simple, but not silly.  That's why I thought to look there!

Comment: @rudtek if you'd like to move your comment to an answer, I'd gladly mark it as "the one"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied and pasted your code. It works fine in both the CPT structure and when I go to the appearance/ menu section.

Have you checked under screen options on the menus section to see if you have it hidden?  I've had that happen more than a couple times!